# How to call a function in a js file from another function in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  app.js file with a function called `getdata()`, and another js file called common.js with a function called `gethost()`;

Now I want to call gethost() function in the common.js file using `getdata()` function in app.js.
Can someone please help me to do this.

I don't want to do this  `script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/common.js"`

```
script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/app.js"
```

in aspx file.

Comment: you just need to refer the 2 js files in the web page. Then you can call the functions in both.

Comment: @nipuna weerasinghe did my suggestion work work

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this just fine as long as you include common.js before app.js

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are loading the common.js file before the app.js file.

You're essentially putting both functions in the global scope which isn't the best of practices though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do that:

```
var commonFile = document.createElement('script');
commonFile.src = '/thePathToYourScript/common.js';
document.head.appendChild(commonFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [jQuery.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to get the second JS file into the HTML page.

Say you have, `first.js` & `second.js`.

A Sample would be (`first.js`):

```
$.getScript("second.js").done(function( script, textStatus ) {

    // call the function from the second js file here

  })
});
```

Or you could include both in the same HTML, ideally.

Comment: Hi All,Thank you very much for your support. Much appreciate your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about loading order. If common.js is loaded before app.js, it should work. If not, please post some example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="common.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

and in your `app.js` use;

```
function getdata() {
    ......
    gethost();
    ...

}
```

Just put `common.js` before `app.js`

**Edit:** If you want to do that without `<script src="...`, you can use following;
in `app.js`;

```
$.getScript('path_to_common.js',function(){
   gethost();
});
```

Comment: The OP specifically said not to use "<script src="